# Swift: Variable used within its own value in a block

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a project on which we've overridden `UIViewController` to `MyController`, and every `MyController` has an `MyControllerEvent` var containing the navigation/segues with other controllers. For example:

```
struct HomeControllerEvent: MyControllerEvent {
    var goToSettings: () -> ()
    var goToHelp: () -> ()
}

class HomeController: MyController {

    var event: HomeControllerEvent?

    init(_ event: HomeControllerEvent) {
        self.event = event
    }
}
```

This way, I'm initializing `HomeController` like this:

```
var homeController: HomeController(goToSettings: {
    self.navigationController?.push(SettingsController())
}, goToHelp: {
    self.navigationController?.push(HelpController())    
})
```

But I have a problem in some cases, when I need to push the same previous event:

```
var otherController: OtherController(pushAgain: {
    self.navigationController?.push(OtherController(otherController.event))
})
```

When doing so, I get an error :

> Variable used within its own value

So how can I solve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the event to a different variable prior to adding it to the initializer:

```
var otherController: OtherController(pushAgain: {
    let event = otherController.event
    self.navigationController?.push(OtherController(event))
})
```

**EDIT:**
Instead of doing so, which is awkward, try initializing first, and have a setter for the "pushAgain":

```
var otherController : OtherController = OtherController(...);
otherController.setExtraPush(OtherController(otherController.event))
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work, the event is still being created while initializing the parent controller here

Comment: I just noticed something, the initialization is in the variable type definition rather than: = OtherController, also, the event was not yet created, because the initialization was not done, check my edit